# How could I make a dynamic HTML table with number of cells given?

Tags: html, dynamic, html-table

Need some help..
I need to implement an  dynamic HTML table.
I need to insert given number of cells to equal number of cols with many rows.
I want each row width will be as same as viewport width, so the number of cells each row will be blocked by viewport width. I also want that when every row reach the limited width(as viewport) I will set a new row and keep adding cells.

My JS so far:

```
function createTable(numOfCubes){
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = document.createElement("tr");

for(var i=0; i < numOfCubes; i++){
    
    var redCube = document.createElement("td");
    redCube.className = "redCube";
    redCube.setAttribute("onclick","showPosition(this)")
    table.append(row);
    row.append(redCube);
    }
```

Hope someone may help me, I searched whole internet and didnt found a solution.
Thanks

Comment: You should add some more context: Where are you going to create that table? server side (PHP, ASP, NodeJS...)? Cliente Side (JS)?

Comment: Also, what size the table would be if the number is 48? 4 rows and 12 cols? 12 rows and 4 cols? 3 rows and 16 cols?. It is also a good idea to at least try some code and show us that you have tried

Comment: I have solved it for you, just two second after the question is closed. https://github.com/Weilory/temp/blob/main/table.html

Comment: If you would like explanation, please reply to this comment. In addition, asking a good question with **what you have tried**, **what the expected result is** is extremely important, please have a read at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Welcome to SO.

Comment: @tomer-haliva I think the best approach is using css grid. check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115822/can-i-make-a-css-grid-with-dynamic-number-of-rows-or-columns